# Flutter : same BlocBuilder on two consecutive pages

Tags: flutter, state, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm working on an application and we decided to use the BLoC pattern.
I am facing a recurrent problem in my application.
Indeed, I created a bloc called **CatalogBloc**.

On my first page, there is a widget that uses the following **BlocBuilder**:

```
...
BlocBuilder<CatalogBloc, CatalogState>(
            buildWhen: (previous, current) {
              return current is CatalogArticlesLoadIsFinished ||
                  current is CatalogArticlesLoadInProgress;
            },
            builder: (context, state) {
              return CatalogArticlesWidget(
                data: state.data,
              );
            },
          );
...
```

From this page, I can navigate to a page that contains this same BlocBuilder and same widget (**CatalogArticlesWidget**). This second page calls the bloc **CatalogBloc** to reload data of the same type, but filtered in initState:

```
@override
void initState() {
  context.read<CatalogBloc>().add(CatalogArticlesLoadRequested(family: widget.family));
  super.initState();
}
```

So when I pop to the first screen (from the second), the data has changed.

What is the cleanest way to avoid this kind of behavior ?

Comment: First, you can not access `context` in initState. I am wondering how is it even working

Comment: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/210#issuecomment-482205559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First solution**: see w461 answer.

**Second solution**: in my case, I think it is better to create new states for each page.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new instance of that bloc for the 2nd page